# SQL query in php file error

Tags: php, android, sql, json

I have this code passing a variable from a url. When i use $_GET method it returns me a json with no products found but when i give manually the the value that $user_email has from the url it returns me the correct json! what is wrong and how can i correct it? thank you

URL: http://***********************/android_connect/get_all_products.php?user_email=m

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$user_email= $_GET['user_email'];



// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$test= "SELECT *FROM products WHERE user_email= '" .$user_email. "'";


//echo $test;
$result = mysql_query($test) or die(mysql_error());








// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
        $product["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
        $product["email"] = $row["email"];
        $product["phone"] = $row["phone"];
        $product["address"] = $row["address"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        $product["user_email"] = $row["user_email"];


        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
     } else {
    // no products found
 $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
        }
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET['user_email'])` output?

Comment: and your not POSTing to this method either by any chance?

Comment: string(1) "m"  this is the output of var_dump($_GET['user_email'])

Comment: if instead of  $user_email= $_GET['user_email']; i have $user_email='m'; its working fine! i really cannot undrestand where the problem is! please help

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$test= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_email = '$user_email'";
```

**EDIT:**

```
$test= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_email = $user_email";
```

Comment: It uses the value in my queries. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, your first *was* correct (PHP variable expansion in " double-quoted strings). The second, without SQL quotes for the resulting string literal, is not. Neither of these, however, fix a problem in the OP's code -- that line of their code is correct & well-formed.

Comment: I don't mean to be blunt, but unless you are running his code on your end, that's not your decision to make.

Comment: SQL query without quoting string literals is not correct syntax. His original line of his code appears clearly correct & well-formed.. if you have a reference otherwise, post it. You are coming across as unproductive & impolite here. I refer you to the ANSI SQL standard and MySQL reference for further education: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/231010-passing-string-variable-into-mysql-query/  I'm not trying to be impolite or unproductive. Maybe your time could be better spent solving the posters issue instead of downgrading people who are trying to make suggestions. I personally have had different results using different string annotation within mysql query. So lets all work towards a solution here.